# Pass code to Input of Rmarkdown render function instead of a file

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

I have a workflow with `Rmarkdown` and `render` that feels far from optimal.  Here is what I am currently doing.

I have an `.R` script that may have several hundred lines of code already and several dozen objects in my environment.  Near or at the end of the script, I'd like to utilize `render` to generate some HTML output using objects in my current environment.  To accomplish this, I save the objects of interest and re-load them in the script that I pass to `render` all while being careful about working directories and where items are located relative to the script I will use to render the html document.

Here is a reproducible example of my current workflow and an example of what I'd like to do.

```
# Imagine I have a local data.frame/object I am interested in plotting to html via render
iris_revised <- iris

# My current workflow is to save this object
save(iris_revised, file = 'data/iris_revised.Rdata')

# And then call another script via the render function
rmarkdown::render('R/plot_iris_revised.R', output_format = 'html_document')
```

Where `R/plot_iris_revised.R` contains the following code.

```
library(ggplot2)
load('../data/iris_revised.Rdata')

for(Species in levels(iris_revised$Species)){
    cat('#', Species, '\n')
    p <- ggplot(iris_revised[iris_revised$Species == Species,], aes(x = 
Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
        geom_point()
    print(p)
}
```

Ideally instead of the additional overhead of calling a different script, I'd be able to user `render` directly at the end of my current script, something akin to the code below (which obviously does not work).

```
# Ideally I could just do something like this, where I could just render html in the same workflow
input_text <- "
for(Species in levels(iris_revised$Species)){
    cat('#', Species, '\n')
    p <- ggplot(iris_revised[iris_revised$Species == Species,], aes(x = 
Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
        geom_point()
    print(p)
}
"
rmarkdown::render(input_text, output_format = 'html_document')
```

I am looking for a solution **without** changing the original `.R` to `.Rmd` or an R notebook.

Aside from the ideal capability I present above, I am open to general workflow suggestions of how to easily render some Rmarkdown output at the end of an `.R` script.

Comment: A simple generic approach to this is to split your R script file into several files, with one script file for each HTML file that you want to generate, and other scripts to prepare the data for those. Then manage this workflow with a script (or makefile) that runs each script in the proper order to generate the objects needed by other scripts, and finally runs `knitr::spin` on the script files that you want to output HTML files. This approach will save you from having code as a quoted string (as in your example), which is bad for reproducibility.

Comment: The `knitr::spin` is a very useful Rmarkdown/knitr secrets that doesn't get a lot of attention. Good suggestion

Answer (score 5):

Since the `input` argument refers to an input file, you can just write `input_text` to a (possibly temporary) file:

```
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".R")
cat(input_text, file = tmp)
rmarkdown::render(tmp, output_format = "html_document", output_dir = getwd())
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue seems to be that you want to have .R files that you can source and debug in the console per usual but you'd also like to generate reports from the results.

I use .R files with embedded Roxygen2 code to achieve this. Save the following script as a .R file. You'll be able to source it and see the plots in the RStudio Plots pane.

You'll also be able to select File > Compile Report... --- which will generate an HTML report you can view in RStudio's Viewer pane and will generate a .html file that matches your .R script's filename.

Since Roxygen is preceded by #', the R Console sees those as script comment lines while the knitr process sees them as Markdown and YAML.

Lines that begin with #+ are chunk options lines:

```
#+ setup, echo = TRUE
```

is the same as the RMarkdown

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE}

```
````

For more on this approach see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html

On to my solution:

```
#' ---
#' title: Iris Report
#' author: ""
#' date: "Prepared on `r Sys.Date()`"
#' output:
#'   html_document:
#'     toc: true
#'     df_print: paged
#' ---


#+ setup, echo = FALSE
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = NA, echo = FALSE)

#' # Introduction
#' You can include text in your report.

#+ prep_data

# Imagine I have a local data.frame/object I am interested in plotting to html via render
iris_revised <- iris

#' You can also include tables:
iris_revised

#' # Visualization
#' The text you include can have inline R code chunks: `r nrow(iris_revised)` observations of `r ncol(iris_revised)` parameters.

#+ visualize
library(ggplot2)

for(Species in levels(iris_revised$Species)){
  # cat('#', Species, '\n')
  p <- ggplot(iris_revised[iris_revised$Species == Species,],
              aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(Species)
  print(p)
}
```

Comment: in line R code chunks with `r <code>` dont seem to be getting evaluated

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

`output_rmd.R`: a function that takes your code chunk as a character string, the variables called in the string as a named list, & a file path for the output html document:

```
output_rmd <-  function(input_values, code_chunk, file_path) {
  
  input_values$code_chunk <- code_chunk
  render_dir <- fs::path_temp(round(runif(1, 100000, 1000000), 0))
  rmd_path <- file.path(render_dir, "input.Rmd")
  output_path <- file.path(render_dir, "outputs.Rdata")
  fs::dir_create(render_dir, recurse = TRUE)
  save(input_values, file = output_path)
  
  if (!fs::file_exists(rmd_path)) {
    fs::file_copy("input.Rmd", rmd_path)
  }
  
  out <- rmarkdown::render(rmd_path)
  file.copy(out, file_path)
}
```

The function looks for an `input.Rmd` file in the working directory that serves as a template to render the code chunk within the environment of the list object that you pass. The template gets copied to the the temp directory where it is then rendered and the final html output file is copied from the temp directory to whatever you set `file_path` location to. The `input.Rmd` should look like:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


```{r include = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
load("outputs.Rdata")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
with(input_values, {
  eval(rlang::parse_expr(code_chunk))
})
```
````

So my file structure looks like:

```
- myproject:
  - output_rmd.R
  - input.Rmd
```

Running this:

```
dummy_environment <- list(iris_revised = iris)
code_to_run <- 
"for(Species in levels(iris_revised$Species)){
    cat('#', Species, '\n')
    p <- ggplot(iris_revised[iris_revised$Species == Species,], aes(x = 
Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
        geom_point()
    print(p)
}"

output_rmd(dummy_environment, code_to_run, 'something.html')
```

Now you have file structure:

```
- myproject:
  - output_rmd.R
  - input.Rmd
  - something.html
```

And `something.html` (image cut off because it was too large for the screenshot)

[image]

Comment: This is great! This is probably a separate question but in case it's easy to answer here -- how to do this in a shiny app?

Comment: @TyperWriter Actually I refactored this code from an implementation I had of it in a shiny app. Happy to send you that- ask another question where I can post my code to!

Comment: great! Here's the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347401/how-to-use-rmarkdownrender-like-knitrhtml2html-in-a-shiny-app

Answer (score 0):

The params parameter allows to pass on a dataset to render

> **params** 'A list of named parameters that override custom params
>   specified within the YAML front-matter (e.g. specifying a dataset to
>   read or a date range to confine output to). Pass "ask" to start an
>   application that helps guide parameter configuration.'

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/render.html